# Construct a table with the index of the positions of sign changes on a matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix `M` with a huge amount of data collected from charging and discharging of batteries.
To know the index of the start and the end of each charge and discharge and calculate some others parameters (Capacity and energy) I did the following code.

It works well if the size of my data is small otherwise it toke an eternity to do it.
I would like to know if there is any other way I can do it.

Thank you for your help!

```
M = load(ChargeDischargeData);       

Cap=[]; % capacity charged or discharged
Tab=[];% [state |StartTime | StartIndex  | EndTime | EndIndex | Capacity | Energy]

State=sign(M(1,4)); % State==-1 is a charge and State==1 is discharge
i_srt=1;capacity=0;energy=0;
filt=200;% minimun point need to consider as a valid charge or discharge


for j=2:size(M,1)
    if (sign(M(j,4))~=State)
        if j<filt
            State=sign(M(1,4));i_srt=j;
        elseif j+filt>size(M,1)
            Tab=[Tab;State M(i_srt,1) i_srt M(j-1,1) j-1 capacity energy];
            State=sign(M(j,4));i_srt=j;capacity=0;energy=0;
        elseif (sign(M(j+filt,4))==sign(M(j,4)))
            Tab=[Tab;State M(i_srt,1) i_srt M(j-1,1) j-1 capacity energy];
            State=sign(M(j,4));i_srt=j;capacity=0;energy=0;
        end
    else
        capacity=capacity+abs(M(j,4))*(M(j,1)-M(j-1,1));
        if State==1 %Discharging
            energy=energy+abs(M(j,2)*M(j,4)*(M(j,1)-M(j-1,1)));  %energy during discharge
        elseif State==-1 %Charging
            energy=energy+abs((M(j,3)-M(j,2))*M(j,4)*(M(j,1)-M(j-1,1)));   %energy during charge
        end
    end
    Cap=[Cap;capacity];  %create a matrix with the evolution of the capacity
end
```

Comment: Please don't spam tags; [tag:matlab] is the only one out of the 4 that relates to your question.

Comment: Post a small example with input and desired output. It's hard to guess what you want from your code

Comment: Thank you  Luis Mendo, I edited my question.

Comment: I would guess that some of the time is eaten by resizing the Cap and Tab variables on each iteration. Consider preallocating space using `zeros` before the for loop and indexing into the matrix to enter the calculated values.

Comment: MATLAB strongly recommends that when you know the size of an array, initialize it so. This ensures that memory is allocated for your data and reduces a lot of overhead from having to shift and allocate new memory. Try something like: Cap = zeros(M-1, 1), and assign values by index, and not concatenate. This is the first thing you should do to improve performance. (Exactly what @Cecilia said.)